# Today, mysql_real_escape_string() is escaping single quotes AND double quotes

Tags: php, mysql

```
$str = 'BEGIN This is a "quote" test. \'Single\' END';
echo $str . "\n";
echo mysql_real_escape_string($str);

// Outputs:
BEGIN This is a "quote" test. 'Single' END
BEGIN This is a \"quote\" test. \'Single\' END
```

Running PHP 5.3.2 on CentOS. As far as I can remember, `mysql_real_escape_string()` will only escape single quotes to prevent sql injections. Double quotes have nothing to do with that, because `"` does not start or end a string literal in MySQL!

This is causing backslashes to get inserted into the data! Something I clearly do not want.

Comment: What has changed recently? An updated PHP version? Something else? It won't just start doing this without a cause? Did a setting in php.ini get changed?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` sends the string to the MySQL server to have it escape the data, then returns what it sends back to you.  Also, MySQL in its default mode accepts both `'` and `"` as string delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"` does start a string in MySQL. (See: [Strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html))

Exception:

> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is
>   enabled, string literals can be quoted
>   only within single quotation marks
>   because a string quoted within double
>   quotation marks is interpreted as an
>   identifier.

Comment: OK I see that now... it seems I had been using addslashes() in my library's escape function. 
But if I insert this into the database, i.e.
`INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('BEGIN This is a \"quote\" test. \'Single\' END')`
will the backslash-double-quote turn into just `"` or will the backslash be carried with it into the data? This means when I get the data out I would have to strip the backslash out.

Comment: `\"` will be converted to `"` ;)

Comment: ok thanks nikic I got scared for a second there. something else then is causing backslashes to be inserted in my data. (No it's not magic quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like magic quotes got turned on.

This post details your problem exactly, along with fixes.
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=545824

Comment: thanks but magic quotes wasn't turned on. the problem actually was that my code was escaping the data twice (once in a local function and again in a library function), which resulted in `"` becoming `\"` and then becoming `\\"` which would become `\"` after insertion into database.  The accepted answer cleared my confusion up.

Comment: well, to be fair, extra quotes is exactly what the problem was.  So while I couldn't have fathomed that your code did it elsewhere, i did accurately diagnose the cause, just not the agent ;-)

Comment: ah, very true. hopefully someone with a similar problem will seek this question & one of it's answers and arrive at a solution :}