# Why should we escape double quotes and NULL inside MySql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Today, mysql_real_escape_string() is escaping single quotes AND double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575969/today-mysql-real-escape-string-is-escaping-single-quotes-and-double-quotes)

I understand  that single quotes and backslash have special meaning so they need to be escaped if we want them to be interpreted for their literal meaning.

As far as I understand , double quotes are not allowed in mysql queries to represent strings(if this assumption is correct, is this the only reason to escape them ?) and we should use single quotes instead to represent strings.

And what about NULL?  Looking for specific examples to understand why double quotes and NULL need to be escaped.

Just to add, I've already searched here on stackoverflow and I see most examples refer to single quotes which I already understand... But I need to understand the reasoning behind double quotes and I cannot find any examples for that...

Comment: MySql Docs [9.1.1. String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html)?

Comment: MySQL allows binary strings, its C interface functions do not, so NUL needs escaping. Since in MySQL-mode strings may come in single or double quotes, both are escaped. Because m_r_e_s can't know beforehand in which quotes context the escaped strings end up.

Comment: @peterm - +1 Thanks for referring me there for the details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default mode, MySQL allows for string literals to be enclosed in single quotes OR in double quotes.

```
SELECT 'single', "double"
```

For compatibility with other DBMS, and just in case MySQL mode is set to `ANSI_QUOTES`, most SQL authors use single quotes to specify string literals. There's really no advantage to using double quotes. (And why write a query in a way that will cause the query to be "broken" when someone changes a variable in their MySQL server session.)

So, the short answer is that double quotes do not *need* to be escaped in all cases, e.g.

```
SELECT 'Bob cried "Wheeeee!"'
```

They do *need* to be escaped in some cases:

```
SELECT "Sue screamed \"Stop!\""
```

But it doesn't hurt to escape the double quotes in any case:

```
SELECT 'Bob cried \"Wheeeee!\"', "Sue screamed \"Stop!\""
```

Comment: +1, As of now the best simple and easy to understand answer...

Answer (score 1):

From manual; `The mysql client truncates quoted strings containing NUL characters if they are not escaped`

> If you want to insert binary data into a string column (such as a BLOB column), you should represent certain characters by escape sequences. Backslash (“\”) and the quote character used to quote the string must be escaped. In certain client environments, it may also be necessary to escape NUL or Control+Z. The mysql client truncates quoted strings containing NUL characters if they are not escaped, and Control+Z may be taken for END-OF-FILE on Windows if not escaped. For the escape sequences that represent each of these characters, see Table 9.1, “Special Character Escape Sequences”.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

And you don't need to escape double-quotes, but I think this is not a proper way while playing with strings.

```
# intead of this
INSERT INTO table (1, "John's cats")
# preferred by many programmer
INSERT INTO table (1, 'John\'s cats')
# but needs to escape here 
"INSERT INTO table (1, \"John's cats\")"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those references as well...